# Package import failure in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have the following folder structure:

```sh
/main
    main.py
    /io
        __init__.py
        foo.py
```

In Python 2.7 I would write the following in `main.py`:

```py
import io.foo
```

or

```
from io.foo import *
```

wheareas in Python 3.5 I get an import error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import io.foo
ImportError: No module named 'io.foo'; 'io' is not a package
```

I couldn't find any help so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`io` is a [built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). Don't name your local packages the same as a built-in module.

Comment: +1, I went down a rabbithole down below to figure out why it behaves like that though. OP feel free to accept this one since he was first.

Answer (score 2):

While @ErikCederstrand's answer is correct and probably sufficient for you, I was curious as to why it failed so I went digging through cpython's source. So for any future visitors, here's what I found.

The function where it's failing is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L2207

On line 2209, it checks to see if the parent module has been loaded:

```
parent = name.rpartition('.')[0]  #  Value of 'io'
```

Since it has loaded the *builtin* `io` module, it continues on like normal. After the `if` returns false, it goes on to assign parent module which again is set to "io":

```
if name in sys.modules:
    return sys.modules[name]
parent_module = sys.modules[parent]
```

The next lines are what cause the failure, and it's because builtin modules (`io` anyway) don't have a __path__ instance variable. The exception you see raised here are ultimately what you're seeing when you run it:

```
try:
    path = parent_module.__path__
except AttributeError:
    msg = (_ERR_MSG + '; {!r} is not a package').format(name, parent)
    raise ImportError(msg, name=name)
```

If you change your module name like Erik says, then step through this whole process, you can see the call to get parent_module.__path__ works like it's supposed to and everything's happy.

So, tldr: you've tricked the import system into thinking it's already loaded your custom module, but when it goes to try and use it like a custom module it fails because it's actually the builtin `io`.

EDIT: It looks like `__path__` is set here after it goes through a normal import process in `init_module_attrs`:

```
 if _override or getattr(module, '__path__', None) is None:
     if spec.submodule_search_locations is not None:
         try:
             module.__path__ = spec.submodule_search_locations
         except AttributeError:
             pass
```