# ImportError : cannot import DAG airflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, airflow

I have simple code, I am trying to import DAG from airflow

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator,S3KeySensor
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import psycopg2
from datetime import date, timedelta

yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
yesterdayDate = yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But, I am getting Import Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "airflow.py", line 9, in <module>
    from airflow import DAG
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/airflow.py", line 9, in <module>
    from airflow import DAG
ImportError: cannot import name DAG
```

apache-airflow version installed 1.9.0

I don't know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is similar to [Package import failure in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692183/package-import-failure-in-python-3-5/49692407#49692407)

When you name your Python script `airflow.py`, the statement `from airflow import DAG` ends up trying to import `DAG` from the script itself, not the `airflow` package.

The lesson is to never name your *.py files the same as built-in modules or 3rd party packages you have installed.