# Unable to import psutil in Python 3.7 (Import Error)

Tags: python, pip, psutil

I am unable to import psutil when I activated python on my venv, its gives the following error message, which I cant resolve.

I tried to uninstall psutil and install psutil again but it still returns the same error.

```
>>> import psutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/wenlin.kwek/Documents/fp_churn/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Users/wenlin.kwek/Documents/fp_churn/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx as cext
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/wenlin.kwek/Documents/fp_churn/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _kIOMasterPortDefault
  Referenced from: /Users/wenlin.kwek/Documents/fp_churn/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/wenlin.kwek/Documents/fp_churn/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Will appreciate if anyone knows how to resolve this issue, thanks.

Comment: Did you `pip install`ed the psutil in your new `venv`?

Comment: yes i install psutil in my venv.

Comment: how did you installed `psutil`?

Comment: i activated venv and pip install psutil from there

Comment: Have you lower version of python installed on your Mac? if possible try 3.5 or under? https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/380

Answer (score 0):

Does it raise the same error when you activate the venv, open the virtualenv python interpreter and import psutil?

Another cause I can think of is when you name your script psutil.py and within that script you try to import the psutil module.

(see the post of Yong Wang: [airflow error:AttributeError: module 'airflow.utils.log' has no attribute 'file_processor_handler'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340226/airflow-errorattributeerror-module-airflow-utils-log-has-no-attribute-file))